# Radius of convergence and radius of analicity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I've came across the concept of radius of analycity buy I don't really understand it.

I've read that given an open set $U$ on a Banach space $E$, an infinitely differentiable function $f$ is said to be analytic at $a \in U$ if its Taylor series centered at $a$ has positive radius of convergence and equals $f$ in the domain given by this radius.

Then, it is said that $f$ is analytic in $U$ if it is analytic for every $a \in U$ and if furthermore its Taylor series centered at $a$ converges uniformly in every closed ball centered at $a$ contained in $U$, for each $a \in U$, then $f$ is fully analytic in $U$.

Then it is defined the radius of analycity as follows:

Let $F(X)$ be a power series centered at $a$ with radius of convergence $\rho >0$, the radius of analycity $\rho_a$ of $F(x)$ at $a$ is the largest $r>0$ such that $F(x)$ is fully analytic in $B_r(a)$.

After that, if found several inequalities relating $\rho$ and $\rho_a$ such that

1. $\dfrac{\rho}{\sqrt{e}} \leq \rho_a \leq \rho$
2. If $E$ is a Hilbert space, then $\rho_a=\rho$

My question is about if I understand the definition, and the correct use of the inequalities.

If, for example, I have a real infinitely differentiable function, with Taylor series around $0$ with radius of convergence $1$, then can we ensure that as $\mathbb{R}$ is a Hilbert space, then the Taylor series is equal to $f$ in $(-1,1)$?

Or the definition of radius of analycity is only valid for functions defined by power series?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $0\ne x\in \Bbb R.$ Then $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is infinitely differentiable but $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n\in \Bbb N,$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$... So the power series of $f$ around $0$ is just $0$, but if $0\ne x\in (-1,1)$ then $f(x)\ne 0.$

Comment: It's true, I didn't remember that example. Then I think I don't really understand the utility of the definition of the radius of analycity, I suppose it's too deep for my knowledge. Thank you.